# Uptime help just 0 minutes

Tags: c#

I've tryed coding application how long its been running and it kind of got hard so im here to ask for advice, in my file 'profgram.cs' i have a public datetime witch shows the uptime (i think)

```
public static DateTime TimeStarted
    {
        get
        {
            return DateTime.Now;
        }
    }
```

when the program loads i have this code to set the time

```
TimeSpan span = (TimeSpan)(DateTime.Now - TimeStarted);
Output.WriteLine("The server has initialized successfully (" + span.TotalSeconds + " seconds). Ready for connections.", OutputLevel.Notification);
```

then for the actually showing the uptime i have a case showing the timespan

```
case "uptime":
     {
        TimeSpan span = (TimeSpan)(DateTime.Now - Program.TimeStarted);
        Session.SendData(UserAlertModernComposer.Compose("Stats", "Uptime: " + span.TotalMinutes + " minutes"));
        return true;
      }
```

But the problem is it always says 0 minutes? ive also tryed .Minutes not .Totalminutes and it still does it

Answer (score 3):

You're always returning the current time as the start time.

Change `TimeStarted` so that you can set the value, and then set it when your program starts e.g.

```
public static DateTime TimeStarted { get; set; }

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //set start time
    Program.TimeStarted = DateTime.UtcNow;
}
```

Instead of maintaining your own start time, you could use the one for the current process:

```
DateTime processStartedAt = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().StartTime;
```

to get the total number of seconds since the program started you can use the `TotalSeconds` property of `TimeSpan`.

```
TimeSpan sinceStarted = (DateTime.UtcNow - Program.TimeStarted);
double secondsRunning = sinceStarted.TotalSeconds;
```

If you want to create a message to display, use the properties on the `TimeSpan` struct:

```
string message = string.Format("{0} Days, {1} hours, and {2} minutes", sinceStarted.Days, sinceStarted.Hours, sinceStarted.Minutes);
```

If you want to update the console title periodically, you can use a timer. Note you should put this in your main class so the timer doesn't go out of scope and get collected.:

```
private static System.Threading.Timer timer;

private static void UpdateTitle(object state)
{
    TimeSpan running = DateTime.Now - System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().StartTime;
    string msg = string.Format("{0} Hours, {1} minutes, {2} seconds", running.Hours, running.Minutes, running.Seconds);
    Console.Title = msg;
}

TimeSpan updatePeriod = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
timer = new System.Threading.Timer(UpdateTitle, null, TimeSpan.Zero, updatePeriod);
```

Comment: Im new with c#, and i wonderd if you could give me more information on what you mean? do you mean to say change the public static datetime?

Comment: @TeddyRetrosAllRetros - Yes, it should be static. What do you not understand?

Comment: "private set" in the "public static DateTime TimeStarted { get; private set; }" seems to be slightly better.

Comment: It's re-setting to 0 after every 60 seconds, is there anyway to stop that?

Comment: @TeddyRetrosAllRetros - I assume you're using `TimeSpan.Seconds` instead of `TimeSpan.TotalSeconds`.

Comment: Yes, i used .TotalSeconds and it's now fixed to full, thanks/

Comment: It would be better to use `UtcTime` (everywhere), so around the change of Summer/Winter time it isn't fooled.

Comment: Is there a way to set it out such as "0 Days, 0 hours, and 5 minutes?

Comment: @TeddyRetrosAllRetros - Yes, you can use `string.Format` and the a timespan - see update.

Comment: @TeddyRetrosAllRetros - I've added it to the bottom of the answer.

Comment: I did that string.format one, and it says long numbers such as 79599 days and 54996539234 minutes is there anything i may have done wrong?

Comment: @TeddyRetrosAllRetros - Could you update the question with your new code?

Comment: ive set that as the console title is there a way i can make it update automaticly? (refresh) say.. every 5-10 seconds?

Comment: @TeddyRetrosAllRetros - I've added some code to allow you to update the title periodically.

Answer (score 2):

In order to find out the time your application has been runing, you may try using

```
TimeSpan span = DateTime.Now - Process.GetCurrentProcess().StartTime;
```

Comment: Beware the ever present joy of daylight saving change-overs when using local time.